# A Sublime editor feature for vim... File pre-view?

Tags: vim, editors

I was wondering if there was a vim plug-in for the [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) editor feature showing a smaller version of the file currently being edited, generally in the right hand side of the window -- see picture below. First *what is this called?* and second *does anyone know of any such vim plug-in*.

[image]

Comment: In KDE’s editor component (that is used in Kate, Kile, etc) it’s called *‘scrollbar mini-map’*.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called CodeOverview that can be used on windows (and Mac?):
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2888?

Comment: From the link: *To use this plugin, you must be running on Windows with .net Framework >= 3.0.* So, it looks like you need to run Windows for this to work. I tried it but all I could see was a blank window.